# Why does the index method require ownership?

Tags: rust

From the docs, the `Index` trait is defined:

```
pub trait Index<Idx> where Idx: ?Sized {
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

Since the type of the `index` parameter is `Idx` and not `&Idx`, the `index` method needs to take ownership of the value it is passed.

Is there a reason for this restriction? I know 9 times out of 10 one will be using something like an integer type that derives `Copy`, but I'm just curious why a borrowed value would be any less capable of acting as an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A borrowed value can be a perfectly good index, and the definition of the `Index` trait allows for that. Just use a reference as the index type. Nonsense example:

```
impl <'a> Index<&'a IndexType> for Foo {
    type Output = u8;
    fn index(&self, index: &IndexType) -> &u8 {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

So the "restriction" of passing the index by value isn't really a restriction at all, because it allows the person implementing `Index` to choose if the index should be passed by value or by reference.

Comment: D'oh, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that is precisely what the restriction `Idx: ?Sized` means, is'nt it?

Comment: There are plans for Rust to allow passing dynamically sized types *by value* to functions, but that's not doable yet (as of Rust 1.4.0), hence why [`FnBox`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html) exists. When this is implemented, `Idx: ?Sized` will allow DSTs to be used for `Idx`.