# Method `mul` has an incompatible type for trait

Tags: struct, rust

I'm creating a simple matrix struct in Rust and I'm trying to implement some basic operator methods:

```
use std::ops::Mul;

struct Matrix {
    cols: i32,
    rows: i32,
    data: Vec<f32>,
}

impl Matrix {
    fn new(cols: i32, rows: i32, data: Vec<f32>) -> Matrix {
        Matrix {
            cols: cols,
            rows: rows,
            data: data,
        }
    }
}

impl Mul<f32> for Matrix {
    type Output = Matrix;

    fn mul(&self, m: f32) -> Matrix {
        let mut new_data = Vec::with_capacity(self.cols * self.rows);

        for i in 0..self.cols * self.rows {
            new_data[i] = self.data[i] * m;
        }

        return Matrix {
            cols: *self.cols,
            rows: *self.rows,
            data: new_data,
        };
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

I'm still familiarizing myself with Rust and systems programming and I'm sure the error is pretty obvious. The compiler tells me:

```
error[E0053]: method `mul` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
22 |     fn mul(&self, m: f32) -> Matrix {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Matrix`, found &Matrix
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(Matrix, f32) -> Matrix`
              found type `fn(&Matrix, f32) -> Matrix`
```

It's referring to the contents of the for loop (I believe). I've tried playing around with a few other things but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is spot-on here:

```
error[E0053]: method `mul` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/main.rs:22:5
   |
22 |     fn mul(&self, m: f32) -> Matrix {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Matrix`, found &Matrix
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(Matrix, f32) -> Matrix`
              found type `fn(&Matrix, f32) -> Matrix`
```

Let's look at the [`Mul`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Mul.html) trait to see why your implementation doesn't match:

```
pub trait Mul<RHS = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn mul(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self::Output;
}
```

This says that unless you specify anything further, `RHS` will be the same type as `Self`. `Self` is the type that the trait will be implemented on. Let's look at your definition:

```
impl Mul<f32> for Matrix {
    type Output = Matrix;

    fn mul(&self, m: f32) -> Matrix {}
}
```

In your case, you have substituted `f32` for `RHS`, and `Matrix` for `Output`. Also, `Matrix` is the implementing type. Let's take the trait definition and substitute in, producing some pseudo-Rust:

```
pub trait Mul {
    fn mul(self, rhs: f32) -> Matrix;
}
```

Now do you see what is different?

```
// Trait
fn mul(self,  m: f32) -> Matrix;
// Your implementation
fn mul(&self, m: f32) -> Matrix;
```

You have incorrectly specified that you take `&self` instead of `self`.

For completeness, here's the implementation. I threw in style fixes at no charge!

```
impl Mul<f32> for Matrix {
    type Output = Matrix;

    fn mul(self, m: f32) -> Matrix {
        let new_data = self.data.into_iter().map(|v| v * m).collect();

        Matrix {
            cols: self.cols,
            rows: self.rows,
            data: new_data,
        }
    }
}
```

This is a bit inefficient as it deallocates and reallocates the `data` vector. Since you are taking the `Matrix` by value, we can just edit it in place:

```
impl Mul<f32> for Matrix {
    type Output = Matrix;

    fn mul(mut self, m: f32) -> Matrix {
        for v in &mut self.data {
            *v *= m
        }

        self
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my error (and introduced a few others which I can fix by using usize instead of i32).

If I pass self rather than &self into the function does this mean that after I call the operator I will deallocate self?

Comment: @user124784 note that I gave a full implementation that doesn't require any specific integer sizing and is more efficient as well. And yes, by giving up ownership, the values are likely to be deallocated. See [why operators take by value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33709495/155423) if that's not acceptable.

Comment: Thank you for your implementation. I don't fully understand how to implement this without giving up ownership - but perhaps that is another question in itself. Thanks for your patience and the reference!