# Return type is a struct but it expects a reference

Tags: rust

```
use std::ops::Add;

pub struct Matrix4 {
    matrix: [[f64; 4]; 4]
}

impl Index<usize> for Matrix4 {
    type Output = [f64; 4];

    fn index(&self, i: usize) -> &[f64; 4] {
        &self.matrix[i]
    }
}

impl Add<Matrix4> for Matrix4 {
    type Output = Matrix4;

    fn add(&self, rhs: &Matrix4) -> Matrix4 {
        Matrix4 {
            matrix: [
                [self[0][0] + rhs[0][0], self[0][1] + rhs[0][1], self[0][2] + rhs[0][2], self[0][3] + rhs[0][3]],
                [self[1][0] + rhs[1][0], self[1][1] + rhs[1][1], self[1][2] + rhs[1][2], self[1][3] + rhs[1][3]],
                [self[2][0] + rhs[2][0], self[2][1] + rhs[2][1], self[2][2] + rhs[2][2], self[2][3] + rhs[2][3]],
                [self[3][0] + rhs[3][0], self[3][1] + rhs[3][1], self[3][2] + rhs[3][2], self[3][3] + rhs[3][3]]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Code above won't compile. It says:

```
error[E0053]: method `add` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     fn add(&self, rhs: &Matrix4) -> Matrix4 {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Matrix4`, found `&Matrix4`
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `fn(Matrix4, Matrix4) -> Matrix4`
              found fn pointer `fn(&Matrix4, &Matrix4) -> Matrix4`
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8cbed70ce1cbca479ec0d79a3fbb731))

Just FYI, this is an existing trait that rust uses for operator overlaoding. The goal is to be able to do this in rust where A and B are structs that represent Matrices:

```
A + B
```

Comment: I don't get this error; I see ``error[E0053]: method `add` has an incompatible type for trait``. Which is true; `Add::add` doesn't take `self` or `rhs` by reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method \`mul\` has an incompatible type for trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765397/method-mul-has-an-incompatible-type-for-trait)

Comment: You have to remove the `&` signs from the `add` declaration, so the matrices are passed by value instead of by reference, or change the trait implementation to `impl Add for &Matrix4`

Comment: @Aloso, you got it. The &self was what the error message was referring to. I thought it was referring to the return type. You got it. You can answer and I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add()` method of the `Add` trait requires that `self` and `Rhs` are passed by value, not by reference. To fix the error, remove the `&` in the method signature:

```rust
fn add(self, rhs: Matrix4) -> Matrix4
```

Alternatively, you can implement the `Add` trait for references, which looks like this:

```rust
impl<'a> Add for &'a Matrix4 {
    type Output = Matrix4;

    fn add(self, rhs: &'a Matrix4) -> Matrix4 {
        //...
    }
}
```

`self` is still passed by value, because `Self` is now `&Matrix4`.